# What data structure can we use to efficiently check for resource availability?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

*This question is [asked on behalf](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/5p2mko/what_the_mods_of_stackoverflow_think_every_single/dcosuzo/?context=2) of reddit user [/u/Dasharg95](https://www.reddit.com/user/Dasharg95).*

I want to build a hotel room reservation system where each hotel room can be booked for an arbitrary set of time frames. A common query against the reservation data set is trying to figure out what rooms are available for a given time frame. Is there a data structure for the reservation data set that allows this kind of query to be performed efficiently?

For example, say, we have five rooms with the following occupation times:

```
room 1:  9:00 -- 12:00, 15:00 -- 18:00, 19:30 -- 20:00
room 2:  8:00 --  9:30, 15:30 -- 17:30, 18:00 -- 20:00
room 3:  6:30 --  7:00,  7:30 --  8:15
room 4: 12:00 -- 20:00,
room 5:  7:00 -- 14:15, 18:00 -- 21:55
```

I want a data structure for the occupation times that is reasonably space efficient and allows for the following queries to be performed with reasonable performance:

- what times a given room is occupied for
- what rooms are free for the entirety of a given time frame

Comment: You don't need a mere data structure, you need a normalized relational database. Too broad.

Comment: @EJP I am not sure how a relational database would solve this problem. Can you write an answer with an explanation of what queries I can run on what relations to solve this problem?

Comment: The answer to this question is going to depend a lot on the number of rooms, the granularity of the time frames, and the total number of slots available. If we're talking a few dozen rooms for a single day, with 15-minute granularity, then the naive way will suffice. If you're talking thousands of rooms for a hotel where you can book years in advance for multiple days, that's something completely different.

Comment: @JimMischel I'm rather talking about the latter scenario. I'm interested in a theoretical solution, not one that is “good enough in practice.”

Comment: Then the relational database is the solution. And it's not just a simple "here's the code." That's a rather involved system.

Comment: @JimMischel “Use a relational database” doesn't explain the data structure and algorithms behind this though. I am interested in a data structure, not a concrete implementation.

Comment: You can't possibly contemplate such an application without a database of some kind, unless your application is magically going to run forever without any downtime and there are no other applications that need access to this data; and once you start that design process the solution should fall out automatically.

Comment: @EJP If you can't answer my question, then please don't try to convince me that I actually want a different question answered.

Answer (score 0):

The 2D array system can still be useful without a heavy resource usage. The room number could be equivalent to the index- for example, index *i* is the room number:

```
String [] = {"taken","not","taken","not","taken"}
```

An index is the position of an element

The second element, "not", is the index of 1, as the first element (item) is the index of zero. To get the room number, add the index with 1, as if a hotel had just one room, it would be "Room 1" not "Room 0". So the index + 1 holds the number.

If you assign the times with equal size (xxxx.yyyy, with xxxx being the open time and yyyy being the close), then you can cut half of the element by using a substring to get the first four / last four characters for the time, printing it out by putting a colon in the middle of the xxxx like xx:xx.

It could be stored in a simple 1D array, like so:

```
String [] rooms = {"0900.1200", "1500.1800", "1930.2000")
```

...... edit, just realised that those times would be for one room x( ...

So, to assign multiple times for one room you might want to use a formatting system - like:

```
// * = the next four digits are the opening time
// - = the next four digits are the closing time
```

So you could hold multiple times in one element, like: `{"*0800-0930*1530-1730*1800*2000", ....}

Its extremely complicated, but this only uses one array, and the computer could use a while loop to check if there are more times after the closing time -> if there are none, move to the next element / set of times, and room number / index.

Once you cycle through all elements, the room check is finished.

Comment: This is a good solution for many practical cases. However, it has the problem that it needs a quantization of the occupation times which might not be easy. Also, quite a high amount of space is required. Do you have an idea if a better solution is possible?

Comment: @fuz a linked list / dynamic collection might be an idea - it only uses the same amount of ram as it needs, unlike an array with a permanent size, it adjusts accordingly to the amount of data. It is the most efficient data structure.

Comment: With your edit, I'm not sure how this data structure is useful. Can you illustrate how to check which rooms are available for a given time frame? Note that only a small amount of rooms might be available for that time frame, so a solution that does not need to iterate through all rooms might be useful. Also, the list of times a room is occupied for can grow quite large, going through the entire occupation list for every check sounds kinda slow.

Comment: See my updated question for a clarification on what properties I need.

Comment: Imagine I have the booking times of 10 years for each room in the array. How long do you think it is going to take to find out if any room is free today from 8:00 AM to 12:00 AM? I have to read almost the entire database to find this out.

Answer (score 0):

Just imagine if you like to have it in 15min intervall then u would have 24×4 = 92 different intervalls with the first from 0:00 to 0:15. Put this in binary with some added information  to check if you selected the right room u could use 100 bits. Now you create functions to create the bitstring and to decrypt the string an store the strings in an array. Done.

Comment: Note that this is just an example. In a real-world application, there is a lengthy time frame to save (10 years or so), a finer granularity and many more rooms.